# What's an alternative to webDriver.getPageSource() that doesn't select the entire page?

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup, integration-testing

On my current project we use Selenium together with Jsoup in some of our integration tests. We don't want to get the entire pageSource as this is too slow. Instead we want to select the elements we need directly. Is there a way to do this and then still return a Jsoup Element ArrayList?

```
  public Elements getElementsByTag(final String tag) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(webDriver.getPageSource());
    return document.getElementsByTag(tag);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")`

**Code example:**

```
package tests;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import selenium.ChromeDriverSetup;

public class Rookie extends ChromeDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // wrapped driver init
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.tagName("header"));
        String headerSourceCode = header.getAttribute("innerHTML"); 
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(headerSourceCode);
        System.out.println("Ammount of attributes: " + document.attributesSize());
        System.out.println("Ammount of childs: " + document.childrenSize());
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 3173
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Čvc 13, 2022 12:44:52 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Ammount of attributes: 1
Ammount of childs: 1
```